# PHP Validation Question

Tags: php

Is there a way I can check if a user entered only 4 numbers and not 4 letters using PHP? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (strlen($s) == 4 && ctype_digit($s)) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also do:

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{4}$/',$input)) {
 // valid input
} else {
 // invalid input.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ctype_digit won't work user input that has been type casted to integer/float form. Regex is just plain slow - so only use it when needed. So, with that in mind I would do something like

```
$s = (string) $_POST['value'];
if(strlen($s) === 4 AND ctype_digit($s))
{
    // Now that it's verified as a good value
    // convert to int for the rest of the script
    $value = (int) $s;
}
```

This will also protect you from users passing arrays to your string checks.

Comment: Hex notation and scientific notation `are_numeric` as well! Also, what's this about `ctype` not working and user input? That's nonsense.

Comment: Of course ctype_digit will work. From the documentation: "Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical." This is just what the asker wants to do here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's actually the other way around. `ctype_digit` doesn't work on integers which causes problems if you are correctly typecasting your values.

Answer (score 1):

[Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) may be a valid alternative, albeit being somewhat verbose. They allow you to express your validation rules like rules though, which is good:

```
$isValid = filter_input(
    INPUT_POST,
    'varname',
    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    array('options' => array('min_range' => 1000, 'max_range' => 9999))
);
```